# How to use the Same Class on Client as on the Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How can I pass an entire defined class through a WCF service?  I have the class defined on both the service and client side. I keep getting an error:

> Best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.

The whole class was copied from the client-side to the service-side.

Client side calling:

```
TransferProxy.PutTransferOnService(Transfer);
```

Defined on service:

```
[OperationContract]
bool PutTransferOnService(TypeTransfer Transfer);
```

I don't want to access individual items on the class from the client, I just want to move the WHOLE *populated object* through and do processing on the server side.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeTransfer
    {

        private string userID;
        private string transferNum;
        private DateTime effectiveDate;
        private int unitCount;
        private int skuCount;
        private string reason;
        private string localStatus;
        private string destStatus;
        private string carrier;
        private string sourceStore;
        private string destinationStore;
        private string inSeal;
        private string outSeal;

        [DataMember]
        private List<TypeSOQ> correspondingSOQ = new List<TypeSOQ>();

        [DataMember]
        private List<TypeProductList> ProductList = new List<TypeProductList>();


        public TypeTransfer() { }

        // Function adds single item to transfer object
        public void AddItem(int ProductID, string SKU, string PrimarySKU, string SCC, string ProductDescription, int TransferQty)
        {
            ProductList.Add(new TypeProductList
            {
                productID = ProductID,
                sku = SKU,
                primaryUPC = PrimarySKU,
                scc = SCC,
                description = ProductDescription,
                transferQty = TransferQty
            });
        }

        // Add SOQ to transfer object (can support multiple SOQ's)        
        public void AddSOQ(TypeSOQ soq)
        {
            correspondingSOQ.Add(soq);
        }

        // Function returns number of skus in Product List        
        public int GetSKUTotal()
        {
            return ProductList.Count();
        }

        // Function returns total number of items in transfer
        public int GetItemTotal()
        {
            int itemtotal = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.Count(); i++)
            {
                itemtotal += ProductList[i].transferQty;
            }
            return itemtotal;

        }

        // Return entire SOQ list        
        public List<TypeSOQ> GetSOQs()
        {
            return correspondingSOQ;
        }

        // Returns full product list in transfer object        
        public List<TypeProductList> GetProductList()
        {
            return ProductList;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string UserID
        {
            get { return userID; }
            set { userID = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string TransferNum
        {
            get { return transferNum; }
            set { transferNum = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime EffectiveDate
        {
            get { return effectiveDate; }
            set { effectiveDate = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public int UnitCount
        {
            get { return unitCount; }
            set { unitCount = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Reason
        {
            get { return reason; }
            set { reason = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string LocalStatus
        {
            get { return localStatus; }
            set { localStatus = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string DestStatus
        {
            get { return destStatus; }
            set { destStatus = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Carrier
        {
            get { return carrier; }
            set { carrier = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string SourceStore
        {
            get { return sourceStore; }
            set { sourceStore = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string DestStore
        {
            get { return destinationStore; }
            set { destinationStore = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string InSeal
        {
            get { return inSeal; }
            set { inSeal = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string OutSeal
        {
            get { return outSeal; }
            set { outSeal = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public int SKUCount
        {
            get { return skuCount; }
            set { skuCount = value; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have the class on both sides. You just said so. Perhaps you mean class instances?

Comment: Can you show how your class `TypeTransfer` looks like?

Comment: You want to send an OBJECT, not a class.  When you are referencing the class, are you using the same class namespace for both client and server?

Comment: Sorry, yes send the populated object through to be added to server side database. (first time posting on site, like it!)

Comment: How did you create the Service Reference on the client? There's a flag that allows you to reuse the same datatypes as the server is using but to use them on the client as well.

Comment: (Visual Studio 2010) I right clicked and selected 'add service reference' - I've tested the function to just pass a simple string through from service to client and it works fine.  For some reason the it barks at the object. Please Note, I have developed them as two seperate projects though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said - `The whole class was copied from the client-side to the service-side`.

You don't need to copy your class to server side. just define your class in a separate library and give reference of that **same** library to both client and server.